# onUserLeaveHint is not always being called

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement PiP for Android and only trigger PiP for certain screens.

When a user presses the home button on their Android device I expect `onUserLeaveHint` to be called but its not always being called. I'm not sure why, any ideas?

Here is my code:

```java
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
    // This log isn't always showing up
    Log.d("shouldEnterPip", String.valueOf(new PipController().getStaticShouldEnterPip()));
    if (new PipController().getStaticShouldEnterPip()) {
        return;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent("onUserLeaveHint");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O && isInPictureInPictureMode()) {
        enterPictureInPictureMode();
    }
}
```